# Convert a SQL query to MS-Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Just trying to get my SQL query to work in MS-Access but it doesn't want to. I tried to find a guide or something about this, because I know it happens a lot of time and it's often just about adding some parenthesis, but I haven't been able to get this query working despite all my tries:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name AS lev1, t2.Name as lev2, t3.Name as lev3, t4.Name as lev4
FROM Folder AS t1
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t2 ON t2.Parent = t1.ObjId 
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t3 ON t3.Parent = t2.ObjId 
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t4 ON t4.Parent = t3.ObjId 
WHERE t1.ObjId = '123456789';
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The usual Access `Syntax Error - No operator` and then it points out to t2.Name on first line. Not sure why you ask me this. As you probably already know, Access needs a lot of parenthesis and that's why it's a syntax error, but I don't know where to put the parenthesis. I never exactly understood the difference and that's why I'm asking for some kind of guidelines or indications about the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses around each join. When you have multi-table joins, you will have several:

```
SELECT t1.Name AS lev1, t2.Name as lev2, t3.Name as lev3, t4.Name as lev4
FROM ((Folder AS t1
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t2 ON t2.Parent = t1.ObjId)
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t3 ON t3.Parent = t2.ObjId)
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t4 ON t4.Parent = t3.ObjId 
WHERE t1.ObjId = '123456789';
```

Formatted it looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.Name AS lev1, t2.Name as lev2, t3.Name as lev3, t4.Name as lev4
FROM 
(
    (
        Folder AS t1
        LEFT JOIN Folder AS t2 ON t2.Parent = t1.ObjId
    )
    LEFT JOIN Folder AS t3 ON t3.Parent = t2.ObjId
)
LEFT JOIN Folder AS t4 ON t4.Parent = t3.ObjId 
WHERE t1.ObjId = '123456789';
```

Comment: This does work. Is this always the same? All the opening parenthesis at the beginning of the FROM clause and then close one after each JOIN/ON statement?

Comment: @dnLL yes that is the syntax.  Place the opening parentheses at the `FROM` and the closing after each join.